# Use an input password in django models and hash it

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a password field and hash it to have more security, but it didn't work trying to use form.InputPassword. Someone could help me? :)
PS: I saw on stackoverflow using "forms" form django but im doing with models

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4
from django import forms


class Cliente(models.Model):
    id_usuario = models.UUIDField(auto_created=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

Comment: Is this model for a user and will be used for user authentication purposes? If so please read the documentation on [Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/).

Comment: Actually I don't want to authenticate, I just want a password field. But i'll read it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wan't to create custom Django User Model, please [read the docs first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

If you are just interested in how to hash and verify the password manually here is a little code for you to know. But install passlib before that `pip install passlib`.

```
from passlib.hash import bcrypt


def hash_password(password: str) -> str:
    return bcrypt.hash(password)


def verify_password(password: str, password_hash: str):
    return bcrypt.verify(password, password_hash)
```

Comment: That worked! thanks